# Create query in Azure Devops server filtering on User Stories or tasks

Tags: azure-devops-server

I'm struggling to create a query to filter on either the parent user story or the nested child task but I can't figure out if this is possible.

For example:

There is a user story assigned to user A with tasks assigned to User B and C
There is another user story assigned to user C with tasks assigned to user A, B and C.
Is there a way to create a query which returns both of the user stories and all of their tasks when filtering on user A? I also like the hierarchy to be right, ie the user stories should contain tasks as links.

Comment: As no one came up with a solution, I realize there is no way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, check the pic below:

[image]

**Note**: If the task assigned to user A, the parent-child relationship that returns the result is the opposite

**Update1**

We cannot get the result in the one query, we need to create different queries to get results.

Task assign to A

[image]

User Story assign to A.

[image]

**Update2**

Install the extension [Query Based Boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.EdTro-AzureDevOps-Extensions-QueryBasedBoards-Public)->create query->save the query and click the tab **Show as Taskboard**, then we could see the result.

Comment: Oh, I see my question was not clear enough. I also need the hierarchy to be right, ie the user stories should contain tasks as children in the tree.

Comment: Hi @JanniKajbrink, We need create two queries to get the result, check the update1

Comment: OK, I See. But I need the results in one query to be able to use the extension Query Based Boards simulating the Taskboard. Thanks anyway for really trying to help me out.

Comment: Hi @JanniKajbrink, Thanks for the sharing, I have installed the extension and updated the answer, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I can't see how your update really helps me out? I need one query to display User Stories and their children (tasks) where either the user story OR one of the tasks is assigned to user A. Say User A is assigned to User Story A and User A is assigned to a task with parent User Story B. I need one query displaying both User Story A and User Story B and all of their child tasks. Is that really accomplished in your answer above?